# CSS:how to click a link under mask?

Tags: css, mask

I add a mask on a div while data is loading, then a link in div is not clickable while loading.I want the link is clickable while loading. How could i get it?

```
                    <div id="customerSettings">

                    <input id="licensestartdate" /><br/>
                    <input id="testuser" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    <label for="testuser" >Test User</label><br/>
                    <input id="accountactive" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    <label for="accountactive" >Account Active</label><br/>
                    <input id="emailoutput" type="checkbox" value="true" />
                    <label for="emailoutput" >Email Output</label><br/>
                </div>
```

I use kendo ui progress like this [enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/bundyo/64CRY/31/),
when mask is on the div #customerSettings, i want the checkbox is clickalbe.

Comment: Shared the code which you have tried.

Comment: Please provide the code of what you have done or tried

Comment: `z-index` to put link above mask.

Comment: Have you tried adding [`pointer-events: none;`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) to the CSS style for the element that contains the mask?

Comment: Make <a> tag position absolute and add z-index. Example: `a{ position:absolute; z-index:9; }`. Share your JSFIDDLE code if still you are not able to fix.

Comment: Still not clear your question. Two tab is there i am able to click and see respective content while navigate each tab.

Answer (score 0):

When dom elements is not loaded simply write Loading... on your code . Once all the data are loaded use onAfterRender() . You need to use javascript for this .

onAfterRender()
    Click Me